# Returning a count of documents with id and name using OpenSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm hoping to return a count of documents grouped by a property in the document, but I need it to return the key (company_id), company_name and the count of documents. I'm able to return a count of documents group by the company_id but I'm unable to find a way to include the company_name field

```
GET test1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_company_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "identity.company.company_id",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example document structure

```
{
  "_index": "test1",
  "_id": "111111",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": 111111,
    "identity": {
      "name": "Test User 1",
      "email": "test1@test.com",
      "company": {
        "company_id": 1,
        "company_name": "Test Company 1"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "_index": "test1",
  "_id": "222222",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": 222222,
    "identity": {
      "name": "Test User 2",
      "email": "test2@test.com",
      "company": {
        "company_id": 1,
        "company_name": "Test Company 1"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "_index": "test1",
  "_id": "333333",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": 333333,
    "identity": {
      "name": "Test User 3",
      "email": "test3@test.com",
      "company": {
        "company_id": 2,
        "company_name": "Test Company 2"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "_index": "test1",
  "_id": "444444",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": 444444,
    "identity": {
      "name": "Test User 4",
      "email": "test4@test.com",
      "company": {
        "company_id": 3,
        "company_name": "Test Company 3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, in order to also show the name you have the option of adding the `top_hits` sub-aggregation to show the name field

```
GET test1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_company_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "identity.company.company_id",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": ["identity.company.company_name"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Bonus for those using Elasticsearch 7.12+, you can use the [`multi_terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation.html)

```
GET /test1/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_company_id_and_name": {
      "multi_terms": {
        "terms": [{
          "field": "identity.company.company_id" 
        }, {
          "field": "identity.company.company_name"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped!